# How to know name of functions JavaScript has executed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I received a JavaScript file and demo page .html, .js file contains many functions. When I run demo page I don't know what functions are running.

Is there any way to get name of the executed functions?

Comment: It's not quite as simple as what you are asking.  The JS file may be using some of its functions internally.  The only way to know for sure is to put the code into some tool where the code can be statically analyzed.

Comment: @Juhana: 19814 line, i don't want take time to reading a bulk of code, and many in them i don't need to use

Comment: Try running it through [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/), and see what it tells you.

Comment: Basically at any given moment, there may be any number of functions executing in the 'stack', and many of them will be anonymous functions, so they won't have names. Furthermore, the stack will be in constant flux, with new functions being called or returned at any time. I'd recommend you start by getting familiar with the [`debugger` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger).

Comment: @p.s.w.g Do we care about the anonymous functions, or only the ones that are specifically declared by name in the JS source?

Answer (score 2):

You could load your page in Chrome and use JavaScript Profiling

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/cpu-profiling

[image]

Comment: I was also curious some thing like this.